# React.forwardRef/Typescript defaultProps not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-forwardref

We have a react component library for my own project. It was written in js (Customized material-ui library ;)) ). I have task to migrate components from js to ts, one by one.
Here is an example of component :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import Typography from '../Typography';

import styles from './link.scss';

type LinkPropTypes = {
    className: string,
    component: React.ElementType,
    children: React.ReactNode,
    color: 'error' | 'inherit' | 'initial' | 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'text-primary' | 'text-secondary',
    underline: 'none' | 'always' | 'hover',

};

const Link = React.forwardRef<HTMLElement, LinkPropTypes>((props, ref) => {
    const {
        color,
        component,
        underline ,
        className: classNameProp,
        ...restProps
    } = props;

    const className = classNames(
        styles[`link--underline-${underline}`],
        classNameProp,
    );

    return (
        <Typography
            className={className}
            color={color}
            component={component}
            ref={ref}
            {...restProps}
        />
    );
});

Link.displayName = 'Link';

Link.defaultProps  = {
    component: 'a',
    color: 'primary',
    underline: 'hover'
} ;
export default Link;
```

When I try to use this component in main app, it gives such error

```
<Link>asdasd</Link>

Type '{ children: string; }' is missing the following 
properties from type 'PropTypes': component, color, underline
```

But when I pass all props it works correctly:

```
<Link color="primary" underline="hover" component="a">asdasd</Link>
```

It asks for required parameters such as color, component, and underline. Even if they were in defaultProps.
I tried to assign defaultProps when destructuring props in component :

```
const {
        color = "primary",
        component = "a",
        underline ="hover",
        className: classNameProp,
        ...restProps
    } = props;
```

But storybook documentation can't recognize these defaultProps.
I don't want to duplicate defaultValues just for storybook documentation.

So my question is, is there any ways to assign defaultValues by Component.defaultProps in typescript??

Comment: The errors will go away if you make those properties optional in `LinkPropTypes`, or if you use `Partial<LinkPropTypes>` as the type in your `forwardRef`.  But if you do that then the component is not able to understand that props which were not required have been set through the `defaultProps`.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to remove prop-types and left typescript interfaces all over library. Describing comment and default in interfaces solves my problem.

```js
interface LinkPropTypes{
    className: string;
    component: React.ElementType;
    children: React.ReactNode; 
    /**
     * @default 'primary'
     */
    color: 'error' | 'inherit' | 'initial' | 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'text-primary' | 'text-secondary';
    /**
     * You can add comments
     * @default 'hover'
     */
    underline: 'none' | 'always' | 'hover';

};
```